# Linking to C Library in a C++ application

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, linker, extern

I'm working on a C/C++ application in Visual Studio 2010. The solution has several projects that are compiled and rolled up into a single executable. I'm trying to add print statements to debug a few of the critical functions.

I've added a printf statement in a function in one of the .c files. I have taken care to include `<stdio.h>`. The C header is included in a C++ file somewhere higher up. I know that there are differences between how the C and C++ linkers operate and `extern` forces behavior. However, I'm not an expert on the nuances.

The code is set up in the following manner:

```
    // proc.h
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    void do_stuff();

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif

    -----------------------------------------------

    // proc.c
    #include "proc.h"
    #include <stdio.h>

    void do_stuff()
    {
        printf("Hello from proc.c -- do_stuff()");
        // Some other stuff
    }
```

When I build the application, I see the following error message in VS output window:
`[proj path]\common.lib(proc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in function _do_stuff@20`

I also tried putting the `#include <stdio.h>` in the header file, rather than the c file. In that case I get:
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol printf`

Comment: This may help:
The project of interest(that contains the c files I'm working with) is built with nmake with a makefile and the resultant file is used by .exe created by several of the other projects in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdio.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

> unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in function _do_stuff@20

This means you aren't linking in the implementation of the printf function, which is located in a lib.

For <stdio.h> I believe its in cstdio?

Comment: But `printf` is in the standard C library, you never need to add it manually to the linker.

Comment: Traditionally that might be so, but if you are actually building a C++ application and just linking C libraries, I wouldn't be my life on it. It depends on the IDE/compiler as well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties of your project and go to the Linker section.  In the Input sub-section, are you ignoring default libraries, or do you have any libraries listed to ignore?

The library printf is in depends on how you link to the runtime (C/C++ section, Code Generation sub-section -- look at "Runtime Library").  The table in this KB tells you which standard .lib to use for each value of "Runtime Library"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0(v=vs.71).aspx

To figure out what is going on, you can add /VERBOSE:LIB to your linker line, which will tell you every library it looked in (Do this in the command-line subsection of the Linker section)